# How to get this using regular expressions in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql, regex, sql-server-2005

Please I need your help.

With regular expressions in SQL Server 2005 i get the house number of a postal address. Everything works ok. But I have problems with some directions.

For example, I have the address `Florecita Terrace 1746-B floor 3`, the number of home you get is `1746-B`, but the same address can be written as follows: `Florecita Terrace 1746 B floor 3` and in this direction get the house number `1746` and lose the letter `B` because it is separate, not united as before by "-"

What I have to change my query to obtain `1746 B`?

This get (the house number):

```
Florecita Terrace 1746 B floor 3 | **1746**
```

This need to get (the house number):

```
Florecita Terrace 1746 B floor 3 | **1746 B**
```

This is the query I use:

```
declare @address table (address varchar(100))
insert into @address
    select 'Florecita Terrace 1746 B floor 3' union
    select 'Florecita Terrace 1746-B blablabla' union
    select 'Street Flor 4141' 

select  
     address,
     --patindex('%[0-9]%', address) as 'start',
     --charindex(space(1), address + space(1), patindex('%[0-9]%', address)) - (patindex('%[0-9]%', address)) as 'length',
    case 
        when patindex('%[^0-9]%' , address) > 0
                then substring(address, patindex('%[0-9]%', address), charindex(space(1), address + space(1), patindex('%[0-9]%', address)) - 
                                (patindex('%[0-9]%', address)))
        else address
    end as 'numeric'
from @address
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: SQL Server does not support regular expressions.

Comment: but this '%[^0-9]%' work fine!

Comment: Yes, but that's all SQL Server can do when it comes to "regular expressions".

Answer (score 0):

You *can* get SQL Server to use full-featured regular expressions if you enable CLR and add a .NET CLR assembly that creates a wrapper for the .NET Regular Expression procedures.  A good example that you don't have to build for yourself in Visual Studio can be found [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/).

Comment: I think its just what i need. Do you have some example o tutorial to learn how to use regex?? or how, using regex, obtain the number and leter for a home number? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @address table (address varchar(100))
insert into @address
    select 'Florecita Terrace 1746 B floor 3' union
    select 'Florecita Terrace 1746-B blablabla' union
    select 'Street Flor 4141' 

select  
     address,
     --patindex('%[0-9]%', address) as 'start',
     --charindex(space(1), address + space(1), patindex('%[0-9]%', address)) - (patindex('%[0-9]%', address)) as 'length',
    case 
        when patindex('%[^0-9]%' , address) > 0
                then substring(address, patindex('%[0-9]%', address), charindex(space(1), address + space(1), patindex('%[0-9]%', address)) +(case when address not like ('%-%') then 2 else 1 end) - 
                                (patindex('%[0-9]%', address)))
        else address
    end as 'numeric'
from @address
```

Comment: If your address always contains number of home as above this will work...just add a 2 with the charindex as shown above..:-)

Comment: Thanks for your help!. but I have a problem, is that in the second address 'Little Flower Terrace 1746-B blablabla', street number stays with the letter B blablabla. How can I resolve this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Your Address contains the ' - ' character only after the home number or may be it comes in other places within the address or not???

Comment: I have edited my code for the bug.Please try with the same.And if you feel it is correct please mark the answer as correct.